# How to structure mutation in GraphiQL Browser Playground?

Tags: graphql, graphiql

Performing established GraphiQL schema within its browser playground, **`query`** requests run without issue. The backend store is initially expected to be empty.

```
schema query appCount: Int!

query {
  appCount
}

{
  "data": {
    "appCount": 0
  }
}
```

Expected **`mutation`** schema used populate its backend storage:

```
schema mutation putApp(app: AppInputGraphType = null): MutationResultOutputGraphType!

AppInputGraphType {
  id: ID!
  provider: String!
  siteName: String!
  externalAccountId: Int!
  ***
}

MutationResultOutputGraphType {
  success: Boolean!
}
```

All attempts requesting `mutation putApp(app)` have failed, assuming that the parameter/fields layout is incorrect:

```
mutation {
  putApp(app: {
      id: 1234,
      provider: "box", 
      siteName: "hqtest3", 
      externalAccountId: 5678,
      ***
    }
  )
}

{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "GraphQL.Validation.ValidationError: Field putApp of type MutationResultOutputGraphType! must have a sub selection",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
```

How to correct this `mutation` request?

Answer (score 0):

Added sub-selection of type MutationResultOutputGraphType

```
mutation {
  putApp(app: {
      id: 1234,
      provider: "box", 
      siteName: "hqtest3", 
      externalAccountId: 5678,
      ***
    }
  ) {
    success
  }
}
```